# Is Ruby code without thread.join considered NOT thread safe

Tags: ruby, multithreading

Working with multi threading in ruby and I wanted to make sure my code is "thread safe". I want to spawn a new thread to allow for CSV file upload.

My current controller code is:

```
def upload
   semaphore = Mutex.new 
   semaphore.synchronize{
   threadCSV = Thread.new do
   CSV.foreach(params[:leads].path, headers: true) do |lead|
    Customer.create(email: lead[0], first_name: lead[1], last_name: lead[2])
    end
  end
  }
  redirect_to customers_path
  end
end
```

Is it necessary for me to use `.join` to wait for the thread to finish to consider this to be thread safe, or does Mutex take care of that?

It looks like adding `thread.join` at the end will allow me to interact with elements in the browser but not navigate it (which makes sense since `thread.join` will wait for the thread to finish processing to avoid terminating any work that is being performed).

Comment: You generally call semaphore.synchronize inside the thread, but this context is a little more complicated because in many rails apps, the server handles each controller action in a new thread. Database connection pools are used to ensure that concurrent db requests work. So I would back up a bit and ask what it is you want this controller action to accomplish. Do you want it to create all customers before redirecting, or redirect before they're created?